# Docker Unable to find image '502:20' locally. How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: docker

When I run the following command I get the following output message. How can I resolve this issue?

```
docker run -it --rm "$(id -u):$(id -g)" -v "PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app \
    rails rails new --skip-bundle --api --database postgresql webapp
```

Command prints:

> Unable to find image '502:20' locally
>   docker: Error response from daemon: repository 502 not found: does not exist or no pull access.

Comment: What are you expecting the `$(id)` bits to do? You are already including an image name (`rails`), and there is no flag for `$(id)` so it's not obvious what you are assuming they are there for.

Comment: I am trying to generate a Rails application using PostgreSQL  as our database. This API will be in charge of managing articles with a small set of fields. I want a Rails application without having any dependencies other than Docker installed on your machine.
I use the official Rails image from DockerHub to create the app. With that image I’ll run a container and pass an entry point with the rails new command along with some options.
$ docker run -it --rm --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w / usr/src/app \
rails rails new --skip-bundle --api --database postgresql webapp

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are adding some extraneous items (user and group ids) to your docker run call:

```
"$(id -u):$(id -g)"
```

Docker is seeing this as the first positional argument and assuming that it is the repository/image name. Running without that argument should work:

```
docker run -it --rm  -v "PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app \
    rails rails new --skip-bundle --api --database postgresql webapp
```